# ML kit object detection appropriate dataset and model

Tags: android, tensorflow, object-detection, google-mlkit

I'm making an app which scans rubiks cube-like puzzles (domino cube, pyraminx, slimtower etc.) and based on the detected faces recognizes the puzzle and shows steps to a solution.

I want to detect the puzzle in a picture, obtain bounding box and then perform image processing like edge detection and recognizing the colours of the puzzle inside of the bounding box. For the object detection I'm using [ML-kit object detection](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/object-detection) with cutom model.

So far I've been able to retrain a model based on [mobilenet_v2](https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/mobilenet_v2_100_192/feature_vector/4) which sort of returns correct bounding box but barely classifies objects correctly and everything classifies as pyraminx (see [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXQ2i.jpg), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOzSu.jpg) or [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7zAw.jpg)). My dataset consisted of coloured individual faces with minimum noise in the background. I've also tried to retrain the above mentioned model on binary images of detected edges as I only need bounding box around the face and don't care about colours, but that was very unsuccessful and didn't detect anything.

So my question is what should the dataset look like? Should it look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hn1H3.jpg) or [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wz4iO.jpg) or [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M82wx.jpg). Also is there any model which would be more suitable for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would structure the dataset to emulate what you expect in the real world. For example, if you are asking your users to put their game on a white background when they take the picture, then use training images on a white background. On the other hand if your backgrounds are unconstrained then various and noisy backgrounds would make sense - such as the second image of the examples you show above.

Also: how many samples are in your dataset? You may improve results with more samples or augmenting your dataset -  [Albumentations](http://albumentations.ai/) could help here.

For classification, I might consider some practical work-arounds:

- Let the user classify the game. After all, they know what game they are playing and could self select this in the app UI.
- Delay classification until later. Just bounding box the game, just like you are doing. Then since you will *"perform image processing like edge detection and recognizing the colours of the puzzle"* couldn't you use that information to classify: number of boxes, shape of game pieces, etc. - or maybe you haven't solved this part of the problem yet.
- Use a two step classification: If your object detection is succeeding, use the bounding box coordinates to crop the image and then feed that into another classifier, which gives you some more flexibility in terms of available models. For example many of these [models](https://coral.ai/models/) although built for TPUs should compile to TFLITE for mobile.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. There were around 2000 pictures in my dataset. However your answer has helped me a lot especially the albumentations module. 
The game classification was kind of out of table as it's the app's job to detect the puzzle automatically. However I've been able to train a classification model and these are my results so far. [3x2_vertical](https://imgur.com/ywx10TT) [2x2](https://imgur.com/SKa8Ko1) [3x3](https://imgur.com/AQp60j0) [pyraminx](https://imgur.com/rPyeEfL).
I used basic mobilenet_v2 model and the dataset was ~14000 pictures (~3000 each class)

Thanks

Comment: Plus as you can see I've used your idea with bounding box as well. I was thinking about it earlier but kind of wanted to let user move the puzzle around the whole screen freely. However this makes much more sense.
So currently I take the bounding box, crop the image and classify it, I get around .6-.9 precision which is good enough for me. Now it's time to start detecting colours correctly